# My VBA code is aborting unexpectedly upon exiting a 'While' loop. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA coding.  I have done some coding in Javascript and C++, so I do understand the concepts. I'm not too familiar with the specifics of VBA, though.  This particular code is for Excel 2007. The sort function was copied from elsewhere as pseudocode (documentation is not mine).  I've rewritten it as VBA (unsuccessfully).

This code is not working properly.  The code is abruptly aborting entirely (not just jumping out of a loop or function, but quitting completely after going through the While loop twice.

To replicate the problem, save this code as a Macro for an Excel sheet, type the number 9853 in B5, and in B6 type "=Kaprekar(B5)".  Essentially, run Kaprekar(9853).

Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks.

By the way, I'm using While-Wend now.  I also tried Do While-Loop with the same result.

Here's the code:

```
Function Sort(A)
    limit = UBound(A)
    For i = 1 To limit
        ' A[ i ] is added in the sorted sequence A[0, .. i-1]
        ' save A[i] to make a hole at index iHole
        Item = A(i)
        iHole = i
        ' keep moving the hole to next smaller index until A[iHole - 1] is <= item
        While ((iHole > 0) And (A(iHole - 1) > Item))
            ' move hole to next smaller index
            A(iHole) = A(iHole - 1)
            iHole = iHole - 1
        Wend
        ' put item in the hole
        A(iHole) = Item
    Next i
    Sort = A
End Function

Function Kaprekar%(Original%)

    Dim Ord(0 To 3) As Integer

    Ord(0) = Original \ 1000
    Ord(1) = (Original - (Ord(0) * 1000)) \ 100
    Ord(2) = (Original - (Ord(1) * 100) - (Ord(0) * 1000)) \ 10
    Ord(3) = (Original - (Ord(2) * 10) - (Ord(1) * 100) - (Ord(0) * 1000))

    If (Ord(0) = Ord(1)) * (Ord(1) = Ord(2)) * (Ord(2) = Ord(3)) * (Ord(3) = Ord(0)) = 1 Then
        Kaprekar = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    Arr = Sort(Ord)

    Kaprekar = Ord(3)
End Function
```

Comment: I think the problem is after looping once, iHole becomes 0 A[-1] is out of bound. and VBA has no shortcirculting in conditional statement. So it crashes. You can create a function yourself call checking() and return a boolean , inside the function use 2 ifs Or I guess what you want maybe For i = limit to lbound(A) step - 1 , stepping backward?

Comment: And the code is all messed up, do you just want a bubblesort in vba?

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions.  Obviously, I do have something wrong, so I will try one or more of your sugestions.  However, I would like it if you could help to unblind me here.  I completely fail to see how (iHole-1) could ever be negative.  'IHole' is restricted to be strictly greater than zero, so at worst (iHole - 1) may equal zero.  If I am wrong, please help me see why.  Thank you.   Ummm.  Hang on...  I just read Sean Cheshire's comment more carefully.  I see it now.  It's unintended and subtle.  I'll leave the comment up for someone else's potential benefit.

Answer (score 4):

excel evaluates both items in the `while` statement, so

```
While ((ihole > 0) And (A(ihole - 1) > item))
```

when ihole=0, returns false for the first test, and out of bounds for the second test, bombing out of the function with a **#Value** error.

A quick bubblesort would be something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Function Sort(A)
Dim iLoop As Long
Dim jLoop As Long
Dim Last As Long
Dim Temp

Last = UBound(A)

For iLoop = 0 To Last - 1
    For jLoop = iLoop + 1 To Last
        If A(iLoop) > A(jLoop) Then
            Temp = A(jLoop)
            A(jLoop) = A(iLoop)
            A(iLoop) = Temp
        End If
    Next jLoop
Next iLoop
Sort = A
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Sean.  I mentioned some of this in a comment above also.  I did not mention that Larry is clearly correct also.  I did not expect a breakdown at the point of test in the conditional.  That was my blind spot.